# besides BM25, whats other ranking functions exists?

Tags: information-retrieval

besides BM25, what's other ranking functions exists? Where I found information on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

BM25 is one of term-based ranking algorithms. Nowadays there are concept-based algorithms as well.

BM25 if state-of-the-art of term based information retrieval; however, there are some challenges that term-based cannot overcome such as, relating synonyms, matching an abbreviation or recognizing homonyms.
Here are the examples:

**synonym**: "buy" and "purchase"

**antonym**: "Professor" and "Prof."

[**homonym**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym):

- bow – a long wooden stick with horse hair that is used to play certain string instruments such as the violin
- bow – to bend forward at the waist in respect (e.g. "bow down")

To deal with these problems, some are using concept-based models such as [this article](http://cse.uta.edu/Research/Publications/Downloads/CSE-2004-8.pdf) and  [this article](http://www.mii.lt/adbis/local2/haav.pdf).

Concept-based models are mostly using dictionaries or external terminologies to identify concepts and each have their own representation of concepts or weighting algorithms.

Comment: Hi @Arman. Looks like the links to the articles are broken. Can you give me the titles and authors?

Comment: hi @swygerts Please visit: https://web.archive.org/web/20100630081952/http://www.cse.uta.edu/research/Publications/Downloads/CSE-2004-8.pdf

and https://web.archive.org/web/20160705074752/http://www.mii.lt:80/adbis/local2/haav.pdf

If you can select an old snapshot, can find the articles.

Answer (score 0):

vanilla [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TF-IDF) is what is often used. If you want to learn about these things the best place to start is [this book](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnlp.stanford.edu%2FIR-book%2Fpdf%2Firbookonlinereading.pdf&ei=LCxXTdaoBYz0swOFuJWjDA&usg=AFQjCNEIufnZmVPa8R58NUvRadWkPSnZFA&sig2=t5dzSo-e1bEYq_I0CxZEAQ).